# Tools --> References and VBA editing window failing to appear in Excel 365 - file damaged?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm trying to resolve a missing reference in a VBA project, but when I go to Tools --> References nothing happens. I've seen comments about it having been moved to a link in the bottom left in Office 365, but that's not there either.

[image: Tools --> References failing to open]

Any idea what the problem could be and how I can access the References dialogue?

EDIT: It turns out that the file itself might be messed up - it refuses to show me any code, and appears to have parts missing entirely. I have updated my question title to reflect this.

On attempting to save, I get the error message "Damage to the file was so extensive that repairs were not possible. Excel attempted to save your formulas and values, but some data may have been lost or corrupted."
[image: Graphical corruption in VBA dev environment]

Comment: Are you by chance running dual monitors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457621/references-in-vba-editor-not-opening

Comment: I am indeed - is that a known issue? Will try the suggestions in that other thread, thanks.

Comment: not a known issue, but i have had similar things happen to me when running dual monitors. If you find the issue, please let us know by answering your own question.

Comment: Fingers crossed. :-)

Comment: It seems to be more than just the References box - the whole VBA screen for this file seems to be messed up. It's working fine for other files.

Comment: If you run out of options and need the code in that workbook, you might be able to use this: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm - After you modify it a bit to be an XLAM Add-In and target a workbook other than the active workbook. (not tested)